# I can print the value in console but not in html view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am trying to show data in dropdown but output is coming on console but not on html view.

html:-

```
 <select ng-model="billing.billing" ng-options="billing in billAddress track by $index">
 </select>
<p>{{billing.billing}}</p>
```

js file:

```
 appServices.getBillAddress(userData.customerId).then(function (data){
          if (data){  
                console.log(data);      
                $scope.addressToBill = data; 
                var billAddress=[];

                 //var billAddress=[];
                if ($scope.addressToBill){
                    storeLocally.set('shipInfo', $scope.addressToBill);
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                     $scope.city = $scope.addressToBill[i].city;
                     $scope.state = $scope.addressToBill[i].state;
                     $scope.country = $scope.addressToBill[i].country;

                     $scope.billAddress = $scope.city +", "+  $scope.state +", "+ $scope.country;
                     console.log("billing address test: " +$scope.billAddress);
                    } 
                   }
                }
            }         
 },
  function (data) {
      if (data.status == 500) {
        $scope.addressError = "Oops! No Address Found!";    
      };
});
```

data has information:

```
  [{city="fremont", country="USA", state="California"}]
```

I am getting error in console:

billing address test: fremont, California, USA

Error: [ngOptions:iexp] Expected expression in form of '*select* (as *label*)? for (*key*,)?*value* in *collection*' but got 'billing in billAddress track by $index'.

I don't understand how  to solve that select and ng-option error. If values are coming on console then Why it's not displaying in html dropdown. Please help me out.

Comment: reproduce the issue with fiddle/plunkr please

Comment: first `$scope.billAddress` is a string and second your `ng-options` has wrong syntax.

Comment: how do i correct those error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `$scope.billAddress` should be a collection, not a single string. Refactor your code as follows:

```
.then(function(data){
  if (!data) {
    // handling this case may vary; here I just clear the collection
    $scope.billAddress = [];
    return;
  }
  storeLocally.set('shipInfo', data);
  $scope.billAddress = data.map(function(address) {
    return {
      billing: address.city + ', ' + address.state + ', ' + address.country
    };
  });
});
```

Second, you need to fix your `ng-options` syntax. One possible way:

```
<select ng-model="selectedBilling" ng-options="billing.billing for billing in billAddress track by $index">
<p ng-bind="selectedBilling.billing"></p>
```

Comment: i got a idea about it. but how about if have more than one address like if i have one more address i.e.   [{city="fremont", country="USA", state="California"},{city="Danville", country="USA", state="California"}]

Comment: In this case `$scope.billAddress` contains two objects: first is `{ billing: 'fremont, USA, Californita' }`, second is `{ billing: 'Danville, USA, California' }`. Shown as select with two options.

Comment: so no need  of applying For loop??

Comment: `.map` _is_ a for loop.

Comment: I modified code according to my need.Thank you so much for help @raina77ow. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This line won't work:

> `<p>{{billing.billing}}</p>`

Cos the `p` is out of range from scope of `select-> options`

just an snippet to illustrate!

https://jsfiddle.net/alvarojoao/7wwdyymz/

Comment: how does it matter coz its just printing wt will be selecting from dropdown.

Comment: options is just like a for statement, when you use a model like billing, this will be available only inside the for statement , if you try to print out side of the statement scope will no print.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you always set it to the last one in the list.  Not sure if that is on purpose.. if so let me know.

But it sounds like you want to set billing address on each item and then use that as the label?    If so set in your for loop data.billAddress = ...  and use the below select.

```
<select ng-model="selectedBilling" 
        ng-options="billing as billing.billingAddress for billing in billAddress track by $index">
```

```
 <p>{{selectedBilling}}</p>
```